# Obtener consulta de pares de valores de dos SELECTS diferentes

Tags: sql, oracle

Cómo se podría hacer un `INSERT` en **oracle** (pudiendo usar `PL-SQL`) de forma que se inserten pares de valores de dos `Selects` diferentes (es decir, obtener en una consulta los pares de valores para posteriormente insertarlos).

Por ejemplo, sacamos mediante dos `selects` con mismo número de filas los siguientes valores, por ejemplo:

```
PRIMERA SELECT: 2 3 3 4 9

SEGUNDA SELECT: 3 4 6 7 7
```

¿Hay forma de obtener una consulta con los pares de valores (el primero con el primero, el segundo con el segundo, etc., de forma que se inserten así?
Es decir, obtener la consulta siguiente:

```
PRIMERA FILA: 2, 3

SEGUNDA FILA: 3, 4

TERCERA FILA: 3, 6
```

etc.

¿Hay si no alguna otra forma de insertarlos así? He probado también utilizando `PL-SQL` en `Oracle` mediante controles, pero tampoco lo consigo.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr tu objetivo agregando una columna a cada conjunto de datos que haga las veces de auxiliar de ordenamiento, por el cual puedes cruzar los conjuntos para encontrar las parejas correspondientes, de la siguiente forma:

```sql
SELECT a.numero
,      b.numero
FROM   (SELECT numero
        ,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY numero ASC) orden
        FROM   (SELECT 2 numero FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 3 numero FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 3 numero FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 4 numero FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 9 numero FROM dual)) a
,      (SELECT numero
        ,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY numero ASC) orden
        FROM   (SELECT 3 numero FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 4 numero FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 6 numero FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 7 numero FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 7 numero FROM dual)) b
WHERE  a.orden = b.orden;
```